# Carrying $_FILES over through a second script/page

Tags: php, file, post, file-upload, forms

I'm trying to carry a file that is uploaded through to a second script. I'm using an HTML form for the file upload and php to save the file. The PHP variable is:

```
$_FILES["Picture"]["name"]
```

I know when you create a `POST` html form and hit submit, then the following page has access to: `$_FILES["Picture"]["name"]`.

But now I want to redirect using header to another page and have access to `$_FILES["Picture"]["name"]`.

Is there a way to do that.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store `$_FILES` array in `$_SESSION` like `$_SESSION['file'] = $_FILE["Picture"]["name"]` and access session `$_SESSION` on another page/script

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the data you want into the session, then it's accessible in subsequent calls.  `$_SESSION` is what's known as a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).  You can also use $_COOKIE to save it to the user's cookies instead of the server session.

Something like this:

```
$_SESSION['picture'] = $_FILES['Picture'];
```

Then to print it later all you have to do is the following, like any other array:

```
echo $_SESSION['picture']['name'];
```

Answer (score -1):

use cURL to request the second page with the exact same headers from the first request

Comment: That would require another file upload.  That's a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: if the two scripts are in two different servers, and for some reason the OP need to pass file from one toanother, i dont see any other way :S
unless of course we do streaming from one server to the other which i guess an overkill for a picture

Comment: Not true.  Database sessions and network storage would solve that particular scenario.  Regardless, OP didn't say this was for two separate servers.

Comment: PS: i assumed the two pages to be in 2 different servers given that if they are in the same server there's no point doing such, if used db sessions still it would be writting a blob and reading a blob + db access issues

Comment: It seems to me that OP has not yet learned how to make the application stateful and that's the gist of the question.